# Leaflet marker icon url compiled wrong while running ng build --prod

Tags: angular, webpack, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

For some reason the Leaflet marker icon url compiled wrong while running `ng build --prod` instead when running `ng build` the Leaflet marker icon url is fine.

My environment:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.5
Node: 11.2.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.5
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.5
@angular/cli                      7.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.5
@schematics/angular               7.0.5
@schematics/update                0.10.5
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.19.1
```

You can find prod env under this [url](https://apothekenfinder.xyz)

The screenshot shows an example of the wrong compiled icon marker url.

[image: leaflet marker icon url compiled wrong while ng build --prod]

I guess it is related to this [issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968) on Leaflet, but I could not figure it out how to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968#issuecomment-371184633 or https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968#issuecomment-399857656?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leaflet rewrites the src tags of its markers in the DOM at runtime, and that breaks when you're using Angular and AOT compilation (which is turned on in prod mode).

You look like you might be using ngx-leaflet. If so, read [this section of the README](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#a-note-about-markers) for some info on how to get Leaflet markers working in Angular.

The TL;DR is that you need to make your markers use custom icons that reference images being processed by the build pipeline (e.g., Webpack or Angular CLI).

First, tell Angular CLI to copy the Leaflet icons into the `./dist` directory. In angular.json:

```
{
  ...
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images",
      "output": "assets/"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Then, reference those icons in your code when you create markers:

```
let layer = marker([ 46.879966, -121.726909 ], {
   icon: icon({
      iconSize: [ 25, 41 ],
      iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
      iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
      shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png'
   })
});
```

That will ensure that Angular CLI will copy all the stuff in the `node_modules/leaflet/dist/images` directory into `./dist/assets`, where you can reference them in your customer markers.

Comment: I can not confirm that this solution works, Angular 10.