# Angular 10 - Leaflet - Webpack breaking URL to marker-icon.png

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, leaflet

This is about the compatibility issue between Webpack and Leaflet. As you may already know ([github Issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968), [SO-Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411497/leaflet-marker-not-found-production-env-angular-7), [SO-Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366041/leaflet-marker-icon-url-compiled-wrong-while-running-ng-build-prod) [npm plugin against the issue](https://github.com/ghybs/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility), [ngx-leaflet readme](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#a-note-about-markers)) leaflet manipulates its URLs to images in a way that is incompatible with webpack. If left unfixed they produce nonsense urls such as `http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/marker-icon.2b3e1faf89f94a483539.png%22)marker-icon.png` as opposed to `http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/marker-icon.2b3e1faf89f94a483539.png`. I can fix this with some solutions on my dev-environment, but not in my prod builds.

I have a single component that does nothing else but build a leaflet map. I have tried the given answers, I have tried the plugin, I remain without markers in my builds.

What should I be doing? What is my mistake?

**My Setup**

Generally I seek to deploy angular on a django backend server. All urls under "/api" belong to the Backend API, all urls under "/frontend" belong to my Angular frontend.

Leaflet is imported in my `angular.json`, but only its js file.

```
//angular.json
...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            ]
...
```

**Sidenote:** I am currently **not** using ngx-leaflet as I didn't see a reason to. I did however read up on fixes that were using ngx-leaflet as the issue lies in the general webpack-leaflet interaction as far as I understand it.

In my component I import leaflet with `import * as L from "node_modules/leaflet";` as well as its Marker class specifically with `import { Marker } from 'leaflet';`.
Using none of the fixes below I get markers on `ng serve`, but not in `ng build --prod`.

Now to my results for every solution. I looked at every solution with both `ng serve` and `ng build --prod`, the latter of which I ran on the dev-environment for my django backend server. Bar solution 3 they always had the same results:

**1. Use [leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411961/7481094)**

```
//leaflet-map.component.ts
import { Marker } from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css'; // Re-uses images from ~leaflet package
import * as L from "node_modules/leaflet";
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';
```

This changed the url to the standard marker to "undefined":
[image]
Markers did not load at all.

[**2. Explicitly set default icon image resource**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411961/7481094)

```
//leaflet-map.component.ts
import { Marker } from 'leaflet';
import * as L from "node_modules/leaflet";

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
  iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
  shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
});
```

This caused parts of the URL to be replaced by an object:
[image]

Identical behaviour in prod. The markers did load, you could see an outline of where the image was supposed to be with a "file not found" symbol.

[**3. Add the leaflet images to the assets and reference them directly in the icon**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53367579/7481094) (also suggested in the ngx-leaflet Readme)

```
//leaflet-map.component.ts
import { Marker } from 'leaflet';
import * as L from "node_modules/leaflet";

...
  //My function to create markers on my map
  createDefaultMarker(mapMarker: MapMarker): Marker{
    return L.marker([mapMarker.latitude, mapMarker.longitude], {
      iconSize: [ 25, 41 ],
      iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
      iconUrl: 'assets/marker-icon.png',
      shadowUrl: 'assets/marker-shadow.png'
    })
```

```
//angular.json
...
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce", "output": "/tinymce/" },
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images", "output": "assets/"}
            ],
...
```

On ng serve: Markers themselves are visible. Fails at loading marker-shadow.png from the wrong url and without the necessary hashes in the name:
[image]

On ng build --prod: Has the nonsense URLs for marker_icon and marker_shadow:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is neither a clean solution, nor one that actually fixes the problem, it just circumvents it.

In the end, what you're trying to do is load these 2 image files. Those **should** come from the HTTP server that is distributing your frontend but that is pretty precisely what leaflet is breaking. Nothing is stopping you from loading these 2 image files from a different place, like the HTTP Server that serves your backend.

Thus, I have uploaded the 2 image files to my backend server and then replaced the defined DefaultIcon of Leaflet's Marker prototype with one whose URL points to my backend server. That fixed it for me.

```
let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: `${Constants.wikiMediaUrl}/leaflet/marker-icon.png`,
  shadowUrl: `${Constants.wikiMediaUrl}/leaflet/marker-shadow.png`,
  iconSize: [24,36],
  iconAnchor: [12,36]
});

L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;
```